# Column widget causing layout problems

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have a list made of `Containers()` (since I cannot use ListView because I need external scrolling), and it's working well except because in each of them, I have a `Row()`, with two `Column()` widgets. The first column should be limited print an image, and the second one, to show certain information in rows. It's a very typical way of doing lists, so I thought it shouldn't cause problems.

Thing is, that the second `Text()` widget in the second `Column()`, seems to always cause the upper `Text()` to shift to the right, causing an overflow and making the text unreadable, unreachable by the user. Look at this picture:

[image]

Yes, the titles are there (even if you can't see the second one). They are just quite shifted to the right. If I remove the description below, they show up correctly, at the left side, with just a little left padding. Thing is, these titles should be there no matter how elements are below, or at least, that's how I understand the `Column()` widget should work.

Take a look at the code:

```
 getListItems(List<Artist> artistList) {
    // Iterate through the whole Artists array and render a list item for each one
    return artistList.map((Artist artist) {
      return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15)),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: artist.avatar)
                ],
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    artist.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
                  Text(artist.description, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ));
    }).toList();
```

What is wrong in this code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the second column with `Flexible` to avoid overflow:

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15)),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: artist.avatar)
                ],
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      artist.name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
                    Text(artist.description, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some modifications to the `Column` which contains the `Text` widgets

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              artist.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,   // can change "0.5" according to your requirement
              child: Text(
                artist.description,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
              ),
            ),
          ],
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexible()` widget Wrap your text widget in flexible widget.

```
  return  Center(
        child: Padding(padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
          child:  Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  child: Text('Hii....helloo....how r u?...here you can show multiple line.', textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

try Expanded

```
  getListItems(List<Artist> artistList) {
  // Iterate through the whole Artists array and render a list item for each one
  return artistList.map((Artist artist) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.grey[600],
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15)),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: artist.avatar)
              ],
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    artist.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
                  Text(artist.description, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Expanded

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.grey[600],
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/100"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("Artist Name"),
                const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                Text("Artist Description"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you can Define the container as a child of `Expanded`(the container in top of widget)

```
Expanded(
  child:
    Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.grey[600],......
```

or you can use
media query,media query, Defines the length or width according to the screen resolution of the phone
you gotta define media query for `height` or `width`
use the `mediaquery`for that, `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,`

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
          height: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`,
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15)),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: artist.avatar)
                ],
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    artist.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
                  Text(artist.description, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ));
    }).toList();
```

if when you use the media query the overflowed error is showing you gotta say
`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` - `the pixels that error says pixels are overflowed`
it means if error says **overflowed by** `128` pixels you gotta say

`Container( height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -128 ,)`